# Aggreage with many group results in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to populate HTML table with some data from `mongodb`. I.e i have two columns to populate. How to make query i.e aggregation that create two columns i.e one $sum second $count, but $count should be filtered by flag:0.

Is it proper method to make one query that retrieve all data? is it possible?

```
  > db.test.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55a"), "name" : "luk", "col1" : 1, "col2" : 4, "flag": 0}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55b"), "name" : "luk", "col1" : 2, "col2" : 3, "flag": 0}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55c"), "name" : "luk", "col1" : 2, "col2" : 5, "flag": 0}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55d"), "name" : "luk", "col1" : 3, "col2" : 2, "flag": 1}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("56d"), "name" : "luk", "col1" : 3, "col2" : 2, "flag": 1}

    { "_id" : ObjectId("e5e"), "name" : "tom", "col1" : 2, "col2" : 1, "flag": 0}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f"), "name" : "tom", "col1" : 2, "col2" : 1, "flag": 0}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("660"), "name" : "tom", "col1" : 4, "col2" : 2, "flag": 1}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("561"), "name" : "tom", "col1" : 4, "col2" : 2, "flag": 1}
```

I want result:

```
{ name:"luk", sumcol1:"11", count_col2:"3"},
{ name:"tom", sumcol1:"12", count_col2:"2"}
```

Notice that for first grouping - `sumcol1` we take all documents, but for `count_col2` we take all but filtered by flag **(count only those with flag:0)**

In SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  sum(col1) as suma_col1,
  count(case when flag=0 then col2 end) as count_col2
FROM
  table
group by name
```

or

```
select tab1.name, tab1.suma_col1, tab2.count_col2 FROM
(
SELECT
  name,
  sum(col1) as suma_col1
FROM
  table
group by name
) as tab1
,
(
SELECT
  name,
  count(col2) as count_col2
FROM
  table
  where flag=0
group by name
  ) as tab2
where tab2.name = tab1.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline) with [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#cond-aggregation) .

```
db.test.aggregate([
        {
            '$group': 
            {
                '_id': '$name',
                'sumcol1': {'$sum': '$col1'},
                'count_col2': 
                {
                    '$sum' : 
                    { 
                        $cond : 
                        [ 
                            {$eq: [ "$flag", 0 ] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
])
```

Result :-

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "tom",
            "sumcol1" : 12,
            "count_col2" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "luk",
            "sumcol1" : 11,
            "count_col2" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```